# Sort matrix based on the nearest distance between two coordinates

Tags: r, matrix, distance

How can I sort matrix based on the nearest distance between two coordinates?

For example, I have this matrix :

```
> x
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    3    9
[3,]    2    6
[4,]    2    8
```

I want the first row of the matrix will be somewhat an initial coordinate. After I calculate the distance manually between two coordinates, I found that `x[1,]` has the closest distance with `x[3,]`. Then, `x[3,]` has the closest distance with `x[4,]`. `x[4,]` has the closest distance with `x[2,]`. So the sorted matrix will be:

```
    [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    2    6
[3,]    2    8
[4,]    3    9
```

I tried to write the R code below. But it did not work.

```
closest.pair <- c(NA,NA)                  
closest.distance <- Inf                    
for (i in 1:(n-1))                         
  for (j in (i+1):n) {
    dist <- sum((houses[i,]-houses[j,])^2) 
    if (dist<closest.distance) {           
      closest.pair <- c(i,j)               
    }
    print(houses[closest.pair,])
  }
```

Comment: What if for example x was instead `matrix(c(1,1,2,2,1,2,6,8),ncol=2)`, would the result go back and forth between row 1 and 2, or would we put in row 3 the pair closest to row 2 that is not row 1 ?

Comment: I think you should take a look at the [travelling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop as shown below:

```
D=`diag<-`(as.matrix(dist(x)),NA)# Create the distance matrix, and give the diagonals NA values.
```

Then run a for loop

```
x[c(i<-1,sapply(1:(nrow(x)-1),function(j)i<<-which.min(D[i,]))),]

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    2    6
[3,]    2    8
[4,]    3    9
```

This for-loop might seem weird! take a look:

```
m=c()
i=1
for(j in 1:(nrow(x)-1)){
i= which.min(D[i,])
m=c(m,i)
}
x[c(1,m),]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    2    6
[3,]    2    8
[4,]    3    9
```

you can also  use `Reduce`

```
x[Reduce(function(i,j)which.min(D[,i]),1:(nrow(x)-1),1,,T),]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    2    6
[3,]    2    8
[4,]    3    9
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution using a loop:

```
## We determine the minimum distance between the coordinates at the current index cur 
## and those at the remaining indexes ind
cur = 1;    
ind = c(2:nrow(x));
## We put our resulting sorted indexes in sorted
sorted = 1;
while(length(ind)>=2){
    pos = ind[which.min(rowSums((x[cur,]-x[ind,])^2))];
    ## At each iteration we remove the newly identified pos from the indexes in ind
    ## and consider it as the new current position to look at
    ind = setdiff(ind,pos);
    cur = pos;
    sorted = c(sorted,pos)}
sorted = c(sorted,ind)

res = x[sorted,];

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    2    6
[3,]    2    8
[4,]    3    9
```